# Understanding stratified approximate randomization test

Tags: statistical-significance, bootstrap, stratification

I have been looking at [a code base](https://github.com/mjpost/sacrebleu/blob/master/sacrebleu/significance.py#L89) that can calculate evaluation metrics. It implements bootstrap resampling to calculate confidence intervals, and also uses stratified approximate randomization for comparing two systems statistically.

The main components are given below in ~ pseudo code, where `bl` indicates system 1 (the baseline) and `sys` system 2.

```
diff = abs(bl_score - sys_score)  # Calculate "real" difference

scores_bl = compute_scores_bootstrap(bl) # array of (1000, ) for n=1000
scores_sys = compute_scores_bootstrap(sys)  # array of (1000, ) for n=1000

# absolute difference, still array of (1000, )
sample_diffs = np.abs(scores_sys - scores_bl) 
# normalized all items by subtracting mean, still array of (1000, )
stats = sample_diffs - sample_diffs.mean()

# Calculate p statistic
c = sum(stats > diff)  # count cases where an item in stats > diff
p = (c + 1) / (len(stats) + 1)  # Laplace smoothing
```

I am trying to understand the final p value, and no matter how I look at it, I come to the wrong conclusion. In reality, the H0 hypothesis is that `bl` and `sys` perform similarly. Therefore, if `p` is very small, that indicates that it is not likely that they perform similarly -- i.e., it means that the two systems perform significantly differently (let's say p<0.05).

But when I go over this step by step, I do not understand it like that:

- `c`: is the number of "extreme" cases, that is, cases where the difference between a random sample of `bl` and `sys` is larger than the real difference
- `p`: so p is the probability that a given random sample is more extreme than the real difference. Therefore, I would expect that the higher the `p` value, the more "different" `bl` and `sys` actually are, because there is a high probability that a random sample yields higher difference than the real difference.

I think that the point that I am missing here comes back to subtracting the mean but I am not sure how to "read"/interpret that.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is here is that you're computing a bootstrapped distribution of differences between the baseline and second system scores under the null hypothesis of no difference between the two.

The algorithm draws $n$ random samples with replacement from baseline and second system values and calculates the scores. These bootstrapped score samples will have means centred on their respective observed scores (say $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$). These are `scores_bl` and `scores_sys` in your code. If we just take the difference between the bootstrapped samples we'll get a distribution of differences centred on the observed score difference (i.e. $\hat{x} - \hat{y}$ ). This is `sample_diffs` in your code.

To make this array of $n$ bootstrapped differences reflect the null hypothesis, the code subtracts the mean of the bootstrapped differences so that it's centred instead on zero, representing no difference. Conceptually, we've simulated a distribution of differences under the null. This is `stats` in your code.

The achieved significance level is then calculated by first counting the number of times a difference under the bootstrapped null distribution is at least as large as the the observed score difference. This is `c` in your code. The p-value is found by dividing this count by the number of samples $n$ and (in this case) using Laplace smoothing. This is `p` in your code.

The reference for this approach in the package is Riezler & Maxwell (2005), although for more details on these types of tests I'd recommend Chapters 15 and 16 of Efron & Tibshirani (1991).

---

##### References

Efron, B., & Tibshirani, R. J. (1994). An introduction to the bootstrap. CRC press.

Riezler, S., & Maxwell III, J. T. (2005, June). On some pitfalls in automatic evaluation and significance testing for MT. In Proceedings of the ACL workshop on intrinsic and extrinsic evaluation measures for machine translation and/or summarization (pp. 57-64).